# Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' to 'UIViewController' in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller for my parent view controller as well as for my child view controller. The child view controller segue into two other view controllers namely "UserLoginViewController" and "RegisterVC". I want the child view button in UserLogin to perform a Button action which in turn perform a segue that involves the parent view controller and its navigation controller.

This is the code i use:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == Constants.embedSegue {
            let childViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UserLoginViewController
            childViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

to call the UserLoginVC from parentVC.

i get an error saying

> Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x109aa7860) to
>   'Storey_Keeper.UserLoginViewController' (0x10645b810).

Help?

Comment: Because the `destinationViewController` is a navigation controller.

Answer (score 5):

`segue.destinationViewController` will be a `UINavigationViewController` if your `UserLoginViewController` is embedded in it's own `UINavigationController`.

You can get it like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == Constants.embedSegue {

        if let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
            let childViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? UserLoginViewController
            childViewController?.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

I would advice against force casting in general.

Comment: UserLoginViewController is not the topViewController for that navigation controller.

Comment: Take a look at how you connected the segue. How are you presenting UserLoginViewController? Modally or push ?

Comment: im presenting it by push.

Comment: make sure to connect the segue to the UserLoginViewController , not to the navigationcontroller containing it.

Comment: Still UserLoginVC is not the one connected to the navigation Controller. its the second on the stack.

Comment: Maybe the segue identifier is incorrect. Check that your storyboard segue matches what you have in Constants.embedSegue

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
 let childViewController = nav.viewControllers[1] as! UserLoginViewController
```

Comment: But UserLoginViewController is not my topViewController

Comment: did you try this ?

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'Storey_Keeper.HomePageViewController' to 'Storey_Keeper.UserLoginViewController'

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'Storey_Keeper.HomePageViewController' to 'Storey_Keeper.UserLoginViewController' is the error i got

Comment: check your connected segue connection and try again this code .

Comment: and give me index of this viewcontroller in navigationcontroller stack

Comment: its the second one on the stack. That is UserLoginVC is being segued from the topViewController

Comment: The childVC consist of two button one of them provide a push segue to UserLoginVC

Comment: hit shows error again. it doesn't have a index[1]. just [0..0]

Comment: then some other thing effect to you

Comment: can you send screenshot for you segue connection

Comment: how do i get view controller segued form the top view controller?

Comment: explain more that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue_profile"
        {
            if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
                let childViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? ProfileViewController
                childViewController?.userId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userID") as! String
            }

        }
    }
```